# Solana Anchor Lang: anchor init creates project with TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, anchor-solana

Confused about what could have caused this to stop working, I installed solana and anchor and was able to test projects.
`anchor --version anchor-cli 0.26.0`

```
nvm use 16.16.0
Now using node v16.16.0 (npm v8.11.0)
```

```
anchor init hello-world
yarn install v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
info No lockfile found.
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 6.07s.
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/Code/anchor-second-test/hello-world/.git/
hello-world initialized
```

`cd hello-world && anchor build` works. Making no changes, I run `anchor run test`

```
1) hello-world
       Is initialized!:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')
      at /home/user/Code/anchor-second-test/hello-world/tests/hello-world.ts:13:30
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at /home/user/Code/anchor-second-test/hello-world/tests/hello-world.ts:31:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (tests/hello-world.ts:27:12)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/hello-world.ts:11:36)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is hello-world.ts test file as generated:

```
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { HelloWorld } from "../target/types/hello_world";

describe("hello-world", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.HelloWorld as Program<HelloWorld>;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const tx = await program.methods.initialize().rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
});
```

I have tried using node lts 16.16.0 instead of the latest lts, starting in a clean directory, checking that typescript was installed, running yarn install before running anchor build command. I checked that the solana keypair and json file was generated in the correct folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this `../target/types/hello_world` directory and make sure it exports like this

```
export type HelloWorld = {}
```

since you have this `import`

```
import { HelloWorld } from "../target/types/hello_world";
```

also, you did not show `anchor` import . It should be

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
```

Comment: update the anchor version. `console.log(program)` to see what it will be logged. looks like it was not constructed properly

Comment: `cargo run` needs a bin target because this is a lib.rs. This was working before without running `cargo run`, following this guide https://dev.to/edge-and-node/the-complete-guide-to-full-stack-solana-development-with-react-anchor-rust-and-phantom-3291

Comment: `avm update`
`Version 0.26.0 is already installed`, seems like this is already the latest version

Comment: did you run `console.log(program)`

Comment: ```anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const program = anchor.workspace.Test as Program<Test>;
  console.log('program',program);``` in the test file, console.log returns undefined, to be expected

Comment: I have errors on the imports, describe, console, and it that were not here before, 
```Cannot find module '@project-serum/anchor' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest` or `npm i --save-dev @types/mocha` and then add 'jest' or 'mocha' to the types field in your tsconfig.ts(2593)
Cannot find name 'console'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to include 'dom'.```

Comment: this is ts error, it should not effect on program as `undefined`. you should have those dependencies `"chai", mocha,ts-mocha,@types/chai,@types/mocha, typescript`

Comment: When I generate a test project using anchor init hello-world --javascript to get a .js test file, I get the error ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/hello-world.js:10:30)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21)``` from `anchor build && anchor run test`

Comment: how are you running the test file? what command?

Comment: `anchor run test`, in Anchor.toml: ```[scripts]
test = "yarn run mocha -t 1000000 tests/"``` This uses yarn, which I tried removing and reinstalling through both corepack disable and npm uninstall -g yarn, but I still have an undefined provider or program

Comment: when you run the anchor build, it will spit out the program Id. did you paste it to the cargo.toml?

Comment: Have not edited the generated Cargo.toml file in /src, `anchor build` doesn't output a program Id, I've been using what I assume is the placeholder id that is in the generated lib.rs file in declare_id! macro

Comment: The guide says I can get this id and then update Anchor.toml and lib.rs, using `solana address -k target/deploy/mysolanaapp-keypair.json` to get the id, then to update:

```// mysolanaapp/src/lib.rs```

```declare_id!("your-program-id");```
```# Anchor.toml```

```[programs.localnet]```

```mysolanaapp = "your-program-id"```

Not sure how, but an error meant I had to generate a new keypair: `solana-keygen new -o target/deploy/mysolanaapp-keypair.json`, I used this new pubkey and updated those values, then `anchor build` and `anchor test` and now this works and test runs successfully

Comment: Something strange is `anchor run test` is giving me a `Error: failed to get recent blockhash: FetchError: request to http://localhost:8899/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8899` but `anchor test` is running the test successfully...

Comment: i severything resolved?

Comment: Yes for now, thanks, looks like I was mistaken in using `anchor run test` instead of `anchor test` or the id needed to be updated in Anchor.toml and the declare_id! macro